# ¿Cómo hacer un buscador con lector de Código de Barras con Macros y Cambiar el Valor de una Celda Dinamicamente?

Tags: excel, vba, macros, busqueda

Soy Principiante en Macros de Excel (VBA), pero lo que requiero hacer es lo siguiente:

- **Leer un código de Barras mediante un lector óptico**: Cada vez que lea el código se borre el dato anterior de manera automática al hacer la lectura, esto con el fin de evitar que se concatenen los datos.
- **Cambiar Valor y Color de la Fila:** Si existe coincidencia con la búsqueda automáticamente cambiara el valor de la celda de *No Registrado* a *Registrado* y pretendo que se cambie el color de la fila

**Código**

```
Private Sub txtFolio_Change()
  cantidadFolios = Hoja1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Hoja1.AutoFilterMode = False
  Me.listDatos = Clear
  Me.listDatos.RowSource = Clear

  y = 0

  For fila = 2 To cantidadFolios
   folio = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 1).Value

   If UCase(folio) Like "*" & UCase(Me.txtFolio.Value) & "*" Then

    Me.listDatos.AddItem
    Me.listDatos.List(y, 0) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 1).Value
    Me.listDatos.List(y, 1) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 2).Value
    y = y + 1

    End If

  Next



End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  contRegistrado
  Me.listDatos.RowSource = "Registro"
  Me.listDatos.ColumnCount = 2
  End Sub

Sub contRegistrado()
  cantidadFolios = Hoja1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  cont = 0
  For fila = 2 To cantidadFolios
    If UCase(Hoja1.Cells(fila, 2).Value) = UCase("Registrado") Then
      cont = cont + 1
    End If
  Next
  Me.Contador.Caption = cont
End Sub
```

**Anexo Proyecto para descarga:** [Descargar Proyecto](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lKaSxghVN5lDwa4G1nIHP4k5Q8Tu4LOc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: No acabo de entenderlo, el objetivo del formulario es simplemente ver si existen los datos que has puesto en la hoja Registros? si no existe no hace nada?

Comment: Por eso puse la pregunta, hasta ahorita solo busca, pero lo que deseo es hacerlo con lector de código de barras, al encontrar la coincidencia me cambié el campo de no registrado por registrado y se pinte la celda del listbox

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de un procedimiento the `change` deberías usar un `AfterUpdate` (así la macro no se ejecuta hasta que entra el número completo y se pulsa Enter)

El código sería el siguiente:

```
Private Sub txtFolio_AfterUpdate()

    cantidadFolios = Hoja1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Hoja1.AutoFilterMode = False
    Me.listDatos = Clear
    Me.listDatos.RowSource = Clear

    y = 0

    For fila = 2 To cantidadFolios
        folio = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 1).Value
        If folio Like "*" & Me.txtFolio.Value Then
            Me.listDatos.AddItem
            Me.listDatos.List(y, 0) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 1).Value
            Hoja1.Cells(fila, 2) = "Registrado"
            Hoja1.Cells(fila, 2).Interior.Color = vbGreen
            Me.listDatos.List(y, 1) = Hoja1.Cells(fila, 2).Value
            y = y + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hay forma de en lugar de pintar la celda de la Hoja1, se pinte la celda de la lista del formulario? Y lo del enter lo había considerado, pero son alrededor de 100000 folios, es por eso que requería automatizar para que se registrarán al buscar

Comment: Hasta donde yo sé los scanners de códigos de barras leen, escriben el código y arpietan enter, así que eso no debería ser problema. En cuanto a pintar la lista del formulario... no sé si se puede.